# Is there a way to make this script run faster?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, optimization

This function goes line by line and deletes rows if the string in column B isn't equal to serverinputvalue or if value in column D is less than `minscorevalue`.

the problem is it runs really slow. Is there a way to expedite this?

```
function readRows() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();
  var serverinputvalue= SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Instructions').getRange('C13').getValue();
  var minscoreinputvalue = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Instructions').getRange('C17').getValue();

  var rowsDeleted = 0;
  for (var i = 1; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
    var row = values[i];
    if (row[1] != serverinputvalue || row[3] < minscoreinputvalue) {
      sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
      rowsDeleted++;
    }
  }
};
```

I've read this source [https://yagisanatode.com/2019/06/12/google-apps-script-delete-rows-based-on-a-columns-cell-value-in-google-sheet](https://yagisanatode.com/2019/06/12/google-apps-script-delete-rows-based-on-a-columns-cell-value-in-google-sheet/) which mentions a method of expediting a similar function but to be 100% honest I don't fully understand how to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function readRows() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var C13= ss.getSheetByName('Instructions').getRange('C13').getValue();
  var C17 = ss.getSheetByName('Instructions').getRange('C17').getValue();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn());
  var vs = rg.getValues().filter(r => {if(r[1] == C13 && r[3] >= C17) return true});
  rg.clearContent();
  sh.getRange(2,1,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}
```

Comment: Excellent! thank you very very much. It's 10x faster or more. It deletes my header though, is there a way preserve the contents of the first row?

Comment: Oh yes. I didn't know whether or not the was a header.  I modified it.

Comment: This script changes the way data is displayed in some cells. A cell with value 02476 becomes 2476. Also a blank cell becomes 0. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: I would need a specific example

Comment: Well when you run it in Google sheets and the first number in one of the cells in the range is a 0 (could be any cell, not necessarily the ones we are doing Logic to) this formula drops the 0… let’s say you have [02345, 192.168.1.1, 15000, 8:00 pm] after running this script that becomes [2345, 192.168.1.1, California, 8:00 pm]. Note the change in the [0] position

Comment: Hey Cooper, just wanted to update this because your code ended up being super helpful and incase anyone stumbles across it. The solution to the getValues setValues causing values like "01234" to become "1234" was solved by first formatting that column to plain text with .setNumberFormat('@').